# How can i see instant trades from symbol with binance api

Tags: python, node.js, cryptocurrency, binance, binance-api-client

I researched so many things about to see instant trades in binance api. But i can't find any endpoints. I can find just `recentTrades` endpoint and this is showing some of the trades I think 6 hours ago. I need to see instant trades. Is there any other document I can't find or is there such an endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the recent trade REST endpoint (https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#recent-trades-list) and limit to a smaller number of results.

Also there is a trade websocket stream (https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#trade-streams) for each symbol.

This will return in real time trades as they happen.